# how to setup spark to use with logi analytics?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am Trying to configure Spark to use with Logi Analytics. So that I could use Spark SQL to query data and visualize it in logi analytics. Any suggestion on connecting Apache spark with logi Analytics will be helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

The Spark SQL is not specifically supported by Logi Info, but you may be able to use an ODBC driver and Connection element to connect to the Spark Thrift Server.

First of all, you will need to download **ODBC driver** **SimbaSpark/Cdata**. Then you should configure the DSN of the ODBC driver. 
After that in Logi connections element add ODBC connection element and set connection string attribute to the name of your **DSN** (e.g. 'DSN=NameOfYourDSN;').